# Delphi XE2: What is the purpose of IMPLICITBUILDING directive found in package

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When I attempt to create a new package in Delphi XE2, there is a new construct in package dpk source file: IMPLICITBUILDING

What is that for?

```
package Package1;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please also see this discussion: [Why does Delphi change Indy's dpk source file when I change project options](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106162) and [this](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ide/problem-with-implicitbuilding-and-delp/1056279).

"The compiler directives which appear between the $IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING 
and $ENDIF are normally passed as parameters by the compiler when 
explicitly compiling a package.  Because these options change based on 
the configuration (debug / release) and target platform (Win32, Win64, 
OSX32) it's problematic to have them statically defined in the package 
project source.  When defined in the project source they will always 
override the options passed by the compiler.  The $IFDEF prevents these 
options from being used during explicit compilation.

In cases where a package is implicitly compiled these options will be 
used, but unless your project was saved in the configuration / target 
mode you want to compile for, you may not get the results you expect.

As a general rule, it's better to disable implicit building on packages 
and compile them explicitly via a project group build or through project 
dependencies.  If you are building for only a single platform using a 
single configuration then the implicit building mechanism is adequate.

IMPLICITBUILDING is defined by the compiler during the compilation of a 
package that is being implicitly compiled as part of the compilation of 
something that depends on it.  As indicated in the comment you should 
not be trying to define this value yourself"

Answer (score 2):

I **assume** it is related to the [{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implicit_Build_%28Delphi%29) flag below the conditional block. I **guess** that it is set as long as the compiler is performing the implicit build (compared to an explicit build). I have no idea why the settings should only be regarded if that is the case. It is certainly not documented yet.

Comment: That seems to be a workaround for the problem that compiling packages with the msbuild script ignored all dproj compiler options because they were read from the dpk file by the compiler.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, yes, that explains it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Am very new to the Delphi ecosystem. Would you be so kind to explain what the difference between an implicit and an explicit builds is? I did search for that but did not find any thing useful. Thx!

Comment: AFAIK (but I may be wrong), IMPLICITBUILD ON means that the package will be rebuilt if needed, while OFF means it will only be rebuilt when the user starts a rebuild. See here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Implicit_Build_%28Delphi%29